# Создать частичный диапазон чисел в C++

Tags: c++, c

Мне нужна помощь в определении диапазона чисел. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы он частично определял диапазон чисел. Например, если ввести от 1 до 10 с диапазоном 5, выводом будет 1-5 6-10. Если от 1 до 12 с диапазоном 5, вывод будет 1-5 6-10 11 12 11-20. Он выведет неоптимизирующие числа и добавит недостающий диапазон.
Моя программа выводит ошибочный результат:

> Input:  rangeStart = 1, rangeEnd = 6, periodLength = 4
>
> Output: 1-4 5 6

Мне нужно чтобы было:

> Input:  rangeStart = 1, rangeEnd = 6, periodLength = 4
>
> Output: 1-4 5 6 5-8

Ниже еще пример ввода и вывода:

> Input:  rangeStart = 7, rangeEnd = 23, periodLength = 10
>
> Output: 1-10 7 8 9 10 11-20 21 22 23 21-30

Мой код:

```
int k = rangeEnd / periodLength;
while (k--) {
    res << rangeStart << "-" << rangeStart + periodLength - 1 << std::endl;
    rangeStart += periodLength;
}
while (rangeStart <= rangeEnd) {
    res << rangeStart++ << std::endl;
}
```

Будут вопросы, пожалуйста спрашивайте.

Comment: Спрашивайте — это когда немного непонятно... А когда всё? :) Например, почему такой странный вывод должен быть — `1-5 6-10 11 12 11-20`? Что за "неоптимизирующие числа"? "недостающий диапазон"? Как-то все непонятно и запутанно. Складывается ощущение, что когда вы сможете точно и однозначно (а еще и математически) сформулировать, что вам нужно, то и сами напишете :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int rangeStart = 1;
int periodLength = 3 ;
int rangeEnd = 6;
int k = rangeEnd / periodLength;
while (k--) {
    cout << rangeStart << "-" << rangeStart + periodLength - 1 << std::endl;
    rangeStart += periodLength;
}
while (rangeStart <= rangeEnd) {
    cout << rangeStart++ << std::endl;
}
k = rangeEnd % periodLength -1;
rangeStart = (rangeEnd / periodLength)*periodLength+1;
while (k>0&k--) {
    cout << rangeStart << "-" << rangeStart + periodLength - 1 << std::endl;
    rangeStart += periodLength;
}
```